# Radio Button in main page populating main page working only sometimes

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, modalpopupextender

I have an asp.net page (Main page). On this page i have 10 radio buttons and a link. When i click on the link it will open up the modal popup with some text and 10 other radio buttons. The user can then select either one of the radio buttons in the modal popup and this will update the main page radio buttons.

I have it all working except the part that populates the main page radio buttons after its selected from the modal popup. it works 70% of the time. Code looks correct but it just doesnt update the radio button.

I thought it was that i dont have the lastest ajax control toolkit but i updated that and its still the same

Im using VS 2008, .net 3.5, Ajax Toolkit 3.5.40412.2

http://2pauls.co.nz/tls/radio_button_test/default.aspx

I have put a page, if you click on framework, choose a number it will populate the main page, do that a couple of times then it will just stop populating

Can anyone help?

```
Code


protected void ModalScoreSelected(int Score)
{
    String strRadioButtonName = "radio";
    if (Score > 9)
    {
        strRadioButtonName += Score.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        strRadioButtonName += "0" + Score.ToString();
    }

    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)this.FindControl(strRadioButtonName);

    if (radio != null)
    {
        radio.Checked = true;
    }
}

protected void rbModalScore01_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(1);
}

protected void lbShowModalPopUp_OnClick(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    ModalPopupExtenderShowFramework.Show();
}

protected void rbModalScore02_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(2);
}
protected void rbModalScore03_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(3);
}
protected void rbModalScore04_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(4);
}
protected void rbModalScore05_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(5);
}
protected void rbModalScore06_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(6);
}
protected void rbModalScore07_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(7);
}
protected void rbModalScore08_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(8);
}
protected void rbModalScore09_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(9);
}
protected void rbModalScore10_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalScoreSelected(10);
}



Html page



 <table>
                        <tr>

                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio01" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio02" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio03" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio04" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio05" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio06" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio07" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio08" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio09" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 27px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio10" runat="server" GroupName="group" Text="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td colspan="12" valign="top">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbShowModalPopUp" Text="Framework" runat="server" CommandArgument="2" OnCommand="lbShowModalPopUp_OnClick" />
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                   </table>

                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbShowFrameworkDefault" style="display:none" runat="server" />                               
                                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderShowFramework" runat="server" X="50" Y="150" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                                    DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="panelShowFramework" CancelControlID="lbCloseModal" 
                                                    TargetControlID="lbShowFrameworkDefault" BehaviorID="mpeShowFramework" Drag="true">
                                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="panelShowFramework" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" Font-Italic="false" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="white" Width="90%">
                        <table cellpadding="10" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>1</td>
                                        <td>2</td>
                                        <td>3</td>
                                        <td>4</td>
                                        <td>5</td>
                                        <td>6</td>
                                        <td>7</td>
                                        <td>8</td>
                                        <td>9</td>
                                        <td>10</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore01" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore01_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore02" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore02_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore03" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore03_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore04" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore04_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore05" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore05_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore06" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore06_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore07" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore07_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore08" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore08_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore09" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore09_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbModalScore10" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rbModalScore10_Changed" runat="server" GroupName="rblModalScore" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="10">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCloseModal" Text="Close" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>                                 

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. If you are using a radiobutton instead of the radiobuttonlist you also need to uncheck the other radiobuttons which are part of the group.